# Arduino - GUISlice - gslc_ElemSetTxtStr not updating the text

Tags: c++, c, arduino

I am trying to update the text of a dynamic text field created in [GUISlice Builder](https://github.com/ImpulseAdventure/GUIslice). The code displays the GUI but does not update the text element on the GUI, could someone point out what I am missing? Thanks in advance.

Properties of the text from GUISlice Builder:
ElementRef: `pElemDol1`
External Storage Size: `7`

The code from Arduino IDE (snipped):

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "test_GSLC.h"

// gui elements
#define MAX_STR 100
gslc_tsElemRef* pElemDol1         = NULL;

// dec functions
void lcdFunc();

void setup() 
{
    // Initiate Serial
    Serial.begin(9600);
    while (!Serial) ; // wait for serial port to connect

    // Initiate the LCD
    gslc_InitDebug(&DebugOut);
    InitGUIslice_gen();
}

void loop() 
{
    gslc_Update(&m_gui);
    lcdFunc();
}

void lcdFunc()
{
  char acTxt[MAX_STR];
  snprintf(acTxt, MAX_STR, "%s", "1234");
  gslc_ElemSetTxtStr(&m_gui, pElemDol1, "acTxt");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyone with this problem:

You need to have the `gslc_Update(&m_gui);` **after** the elements were updated.

```
  void lcdFunc()
  {
   char acTxt[MAX_STR];
   snprintf(acTxt, MAX_STR, "%s", "1234");
   gslc_ElemSetTxtStr(&m_gui, pElemDol1, "acTxt");
   gslc_Update(&m_gui);
   }
```